# CSS drop-down being overlapped by content in IE7

Tags: drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-7

I'm having this issue in IE7 with my drop down. Whenever I hover over my dropdown it goes up as soon as i hover over an element on top of the content. http://www.legrandconfectionary.com/gift-boxes/

I thought a position: relative on the header would solve the problem but on certain pages like the truffle flavors I have a tooltip effect that goes under the nav if done so. I'd really appreciate some help on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways that you can fix this. Here's two:

- Set the `a` tag to `display: block`, and then make your hover events based on the `a` instead of the `li`.

or

- Specify a height other than auto or 100% for the `li`'s

Comment: You. are too awesome sir! I used the height on the li's. Thank you so much.